# Reason behind loss of low frequencies in square waveforms

Tags: voltage

I was reading [this page](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=jVCgti_i7Y8C&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=aC%20coupling%20may%20also%20cause%20voltage%20%22droop%22&source=bl&ots=r2hsTo3Ru_&sig=EvRAHU85lgualcefdqlmMhRZuHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnvan9henPAhWh1IMKHfVSCccQ6AEIPjAG#v=onepage&q=aC%20coupling%20may%20also%20cause%20voltage%20%22droop%22&f=false) of a textbook and I noticed following sentence. I was wondering if someone could elaborate more on following for me please?

> AC coupling may cause voltage droop due to the loss of low frequencies

Unfortunately I couldn't find the rationale behind above statement and find out why voltage droop may happen in low frequencies.

Comment: Simply, AC coupling doesn't pass DC, or zero frequency. It won't pass low frequencies (frequencies close to 0) very well. The loss of low frequencies depends on the coupling capacitor you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perfect square wave has flat tops and bottoms. Taken to extremes these flats are stable DC voltages and, if you feed a stable DC voltage into a high pass filter you get a decaying-to-zero output voltage.

In other words, a square wave droops like this: -

[image]

Of course the droop may not be noticeable: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A series RC circuit will act as a high pass filter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpkdJE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, \$C_C\$ (coupling cap) forms a high pass (low-cut) filter with \$Z_i\$ (Assuming \$Z_i >> R_{out}\$) with a cut off frequency of \$f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi C_C \cdot Z_i}\$. Selecting \$C_C\$ low enough may cause losing low frequency component.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the previous page. AC coupling is implemented by the virtue of having a capacitor in series of the input. Capacitor impedance becomes smaller as a function of the frequency. H[igher the frequency, the lower the impedance i.e. the easier the signal goes through the capacitor](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/capacitor-impedance-calculator/). Formally \$Xc=\frac{1}{(2*pi*freq*cap)}\$

DC (frequency = zero) does not pass at all as impedance goes to infinity.

Comment: That's a fair answer but how does higher impedance in low frequency relate to "loss" and thereafter "voltage droop"?

Comment: @Bababarghi Impedance = resistance. And resistance, well, resists signal passage. More technically you have actually a voltage division between the input impedance of the chip/circuit and your capacitor. On low frequencies where the capacitive impedance is very high this is significant and then falls to neglible figures as the impedance drops. You'd see the "missing" signal if you measure over the capacitor. And cook your circuit/oscilloscope if you don't have a differential probe.